# Getting different result when code is executed in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1 TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'6B75045F-22BF-4BD0-8170-32FA7DBF2A2xC')
FROM [sch_ImmAnn].[viw_mdlImmAnnEle_Formulae]
```

The UID is deliberately incorrect, and when I execute this statement, the value NULL is returned, as I expect. However, if I encode this statement within a stored procedure, as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [sch_Common].[usp_TestValid_UID]
    @ExecUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1 TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,@ExecUID)
    FROM [sch_ImmAnn].[viw_mdlImmAnnEle_Formulae]

END
```

it returns an error when I execute it with the same UID passed through as a parameter:

> Error converting data type varchar to uniqueidentifier.

How can I get around this? And why is it happening?

Comment: You declare `@ExecUID` as a unique identifier and then try to convert it to a unique identifier. I guess you wanted to declare `@ExecUID` as varchar?

Comment: Is `viw_mdlImmAnnEle_Formulae` a view that *itself* attempts a conversion, by any chance? You are converting a parameter (that is already of the correct type at that) so that should have no effect whatsoever (but the optimizer is free to evaluate rows in the view, or not, as it chooses, so passing a literal is not the same as passing a parameter).

Comment: waka, you are correct - that is the reason why it is not working. Once I changed the @ExecUID to varchar, it was fine. Always so obvious when you see the solution! Tks Joe.

Comment: Your procedure does not make much sense as defined (even with the argument datatype change). Perhaps your goal is to determine if the table has a row with the specified GUID? If so, you are not doing that. You need a where clause for your select statement to compare your converted argument to some column in the table.

Answer (score 1):

`TOP` without `ORDER BY` is not deterministic; SQL Server may return any arbitrary row depending on the chosen plan. Add `ORDER BY` for consistent results.

That said, the execution plans are probably different due to different SET options for the 2 queries. Note that `ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` are "sticky" setting for the stored procedure. The settings in effect when the proc is created are also used at execution time instead of the session settings that invoke the proc.